# Images aren't refreshed automatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, page-refresh

I'm using AngularJS to build My website.

When I edit an Image in the any page, the image stays cached till I refresh the page. I tried adding a **"?randomNumber"** to the end of the URL at the backend, but when I check it's value at the frontend using Firebug it stays the same. So is there some method to change the displayed image directly after updating it ?

Here is my code:

**Backend:**

```
for(int i=0;i<X.Count;i++)
{
   X[i].img = X[i].img+ "?"+ rnd.Next(0,1000);
}
```

**FrontEnd:**

Javascript:

```
         angular.forEach(result, function (SData) {
            $scope.X.push(SData);
        });
```

HTML:

```
            <img ng-src="{{X.img}}" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about setting the response headers so that the content is not cached by the browser?

The header should look something like this:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068407/617996) is already great explanation on how to achieve that.

Comment: changing the querystring will make sure not to use the cache